# Why was HTML5 Web Workers support removed from the Android browser in versions 2.2 and up?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-worker

I'm trying to learn something about JavaScript threading. And from a tutorial I learned about HTML5 API web worker. This API enables JavaScript multi-threading. So I start to figure out how and where can I use this feature.

Form http://caniuse.com/#search=worker

I find this API is only supported in *lower* version of Android browser. It is unavailable in Android 2.2 and later.

Is this result correct? If it is, is it because of the performance consideration?

On which version will this API be available?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

from `config.h` of Android 2.2.

---

commit 68698168e7547cc10660828f1fb82be7a8efa845

Author: Steve Block

Date:   Wed Mar 17 14:37:19 2010 +0000

Disable workers

This is because V8 on Android does not have the required locking.
   Also disables channel messaging, which is used only with workers.

Bug: 2522239

Change-Id: I6cb91b4048c7e1a0351e422561625397a2e98986

---

via http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10004#c7

Answer (score 18):

Regarding when the API will be available, Web Workers (but **not** [shared workers](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-shared-web-workers-html5/)) are now available in [Chrome Mobile](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/android/), available only for ICS (Android 4.0) and higher devices.

Note that the built-in browser on Android 4 *does not* support workers; you must install Chrome.

Comment: Late response here, but this is only half true; _Dedicated Workers_ are available in Chrome Mobile, _Shared Workers_ are not. Another twist is that although `('SharedWorker' in window)` does return true, and defining a path does make a request for the file, the messaging seems to be stubbed.

Answer (score 2):

- **Web Workers** are [available again](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) on the built-in Android Browser since 4.4
- **Shared Workers** are [still unsupported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers) on both Android Browser and Chrome for Android.