# Click events being lost?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a web page (JavaScript) that has two types of events:

- Click event in a canvas (only displays an alert).
- Periodic event (fired by a timer) every second.

The periodic event is busy for 200 - 300 ms (it's launching a synchronous SOAP call).

The canvas event:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {alert('Click');},false);
```

The periodic:

```
var timer1= new Timer(1000,"Refresh()"); // A library call


function Refresh()
{   
    timer1.stop();

    // Synchronous SOAP call would come here

    // with the results we draw the canvas again

    timer1.start();
}
```

If I click in the canvas while the SOAP call is being made, the click event is not being fired, or so I assume, because the alert is not shown.

If I click once the periodic event is finished and before it gets called again, every click shows the alert.

From what I know, if the click event is generated while the periodic event is being executed, it should be delayed until the other one is finished.

What could be causing the problem?

P.D. I'm using Firebug (on Firefox) to know when the SOAP call is being made.

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: It would be better to _not_ make synchronous SOAP calls.

Comment: I know... but it hasn't been designed by me, and I would have to change the whole SOAP library. Which will take me some time.

Comment: Upvoted because this is an interesting question that may be of benefit to the community and the problematic behaviour is explained in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synchronous calls block the I/O, so the alerts would not be fired. Since you are waiting for a return for your call, any actions that happen during that time will be ignored.

This article may prove to be helpful: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

> Since **all** JavaScript in a browser executes on a **single** thread
>   asynchronous events (such as **mouse clicks** and timers) are only run
>   when there's been an opening in the execution.
>
> - JavaScript engines only have a single thread, forcing asynchronous    events to queue waiting for execution.
> - setTimeout and setInterval are fundamentally different in how they execute asynchronous code.
> - If atimer is blocked from immediately executing it will be delayed until    the next possible point of execution (which will be longer
>     than the    desired delay).
> - Intervals may execute back-to-back with no delay if they take long enough to execute (longer than the specified delay).

Comment: I read the very same article just before posting the question. :) And that's why I thought the click event should be queued and executed once the other one finishes.

Comment: Yeah, you would think that they would be queued up. However it seems that they are being dropped. This could be due to the fact that it's a system alert message and it gets ignored if it cannot run at the moment of the 'error'. I would imagine logging it to the console would have the same effect, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: In the function called when clicked I also tried logging it with console.log(), and as you say, the results were the same... No logging while executing the SOAP call.

Comment: It's looking like the web workers may be a good option for you then. However, please make sure that they're compatible with your project first: Web workers are currently supported by Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer (version 10) and Mozilla Firefox. Web workers are supported in Safari for iOS 5, and in Android versions 2.0 and 2.1. It is removed in newer Android versions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to decide whether to use web workers or to change the SOAP library to make asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1):

Because UI events and everything else you do in your Javascript executes on a single thread by default what you are experiencing is to be expected.  But this is just the cause ...

Once you understand the cause you are half-way there to getting a solution: if you *have* to have the synchronous SOAP calls, which seems to be the case, you will have to use a different thread for them.  Enter web workers ...

To create a new web worker you call the Worker()  constructor, specifying the URI of a script to execute in the worker thread.

```
var worker = new Worker('my_task.js');
```

To receive notifications from the worker, set the worker's onmessage property to an appropriate event handler function.

```
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Called back by the worker!\n");
};
```

You can find out more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

Quoting from the above source:  Web workers are currently supported by Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer (version 10) and Mozilla Firefox. Web workers are supported in Safari for iOS 5, and in Android versions 2.0 and 2.1.

Regarding Android support: See here: [Why was  HTML5 Web Workers support removed from the Android browser in versions 2.2 and up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523745/why-was-html5-web-workers-support-removed-from-the-android-browser-in-versions)

For an example involving IO:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_workers_in_extensions

Hope this will help you solve your problem.

Disclaimer: In general it is very easy to try to avoid learning how to perform asynchronous communication and web workers may seem like a good way to do exactly that. I am not advocating that approach, but merely suggesting a solution to someone who apparently has not alternative. Asynchronous communication can be quite easy once you get used to it  and will help you build better web sites. jQuery offers good support for asynchronous IO.

Comment: @Arapajoe If you think this is a useful answer please remember to upvote and/or accept it.  Cheers :-)